# Android: Sharing an image from raw folder. Wrong image being shared

Tags: java, android, stream, share

I have an `Activity` where the user can share an image from the `raw` folder.

The raw folder has 70 images, all named alphabetically. The first one is `R.raw.recipe01` and the last is `R.raw.recipe70`.

I get the image `int` I would like to share from a `Bundle` and I have a method which copies the image from the `raw` folder to a accessible file.

I call `startActivity(createShareIntent());` in the `ActionBar` `MenuItem`, which works successfully.

PROBLEM

The share `intent` will always select `R.raw.recipe01` as the image, even if the `int` from the `Bundle` is for image for exmaple `R.raw.recipe33`.

I have shared my code below.  Can anyone spot what I am doing wrong?

CODE:

```
private int rawphoto = 0;
private static final String SHARED_FILE_NAME = "shared.png";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    rawphoto = bundle.getInt("rawphoto");
    int savedphoto = rawphoto;

    // COPY IMAGE FROM RAW
    copyPrivateRawResourceToPubliclyAccessibleFile(savedphoto);


private Intent createShareIntent() {
    Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    shareIntent.setType("image/*");
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "IMAGE TO SHARE: ");
    Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(getFileStreamPath("shared.png"));
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);

    return shareIntent;
}


private void copyPrivateRawResourceToPubliclyAccessibleFile(int photo) {

    System.out.println("INT PHOTO: " +photo);

    InputStream inputStream = null;
    FileOutputStream outputStream = null;
    try {
        inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(photo);
        outputStream = openFileOutput(SHARED_FILE_NAME,
                Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE | Context.MODE_APPEND);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length = 0;
        try {
            while ((length = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                outputStream.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            /* ignore */
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe) {
        /* ignore */
    } 

    finally {
        try {
            inputStream.close();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {

        }
        try {
            outputStream.close();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: why Context.MODE_APPEND?

Comment: @JoelSjögren I don't know why that's in there, but I've removed it and it works now. Thanks! Move your comment to answers so I can accept it :-)

Comment: This question is my Answer. How to share a image from raw folder. GOOD BUDDY!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `Context.MODE_APPEND` so that the file gets overwritten if it already exists.